# Why JSON Response is 200

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

a) Actually I have 1 endpoint which will post to a server using volley. Also my api also have custom header & custom body.The problem is when I want to get the response of JSON it will not display it. Instead it will display 200.For this I am not using form but I just get the body data from shared preference.

b) I have other endpoint using custom header & body but using form which will submit the data to the server. The JSON response is ok and it will display it.

a) JSON response will display  200

//code for a the different is

jsonBody.put("tbid", id);

the id is not getting from edittext like b.Instead is getting from shared preference and I confirm that the id is legit and getting the data.

b) JSON response will display

```
{ success:"1",message:"register" }
```

//this is the code  for b

```
private void requestOTP(){
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMessage("OTP OTW...");
    showDialog();

    try {
                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("tbid", str5);
        jsonBody.put("phone",phone.getText().toString());
        final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_OTP_REQUEST, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OTP Response: " + response);

                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    Log.e(Integer.toString(success),"SuccessRe");


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OTP Error : " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," OTP Error ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }){

                            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }



            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }


            /** Passing some request headers* */
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Auth-Key", "xxx");
                headers.put("Token", token);
                return headers;
            }


        };



        //Adding request to request queue

        requestQueue.add(strReq);

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

c) I also make a new project using the endpoint because I thought the problem maybe the json response is getting from other endpoint in the project.But nothing changed.

d) Already use postman and the result is ok it will show like b the json response.

e) My other  option to test whether it work is  using async task or using form to post the data body.

Why I get different result for a & b ??Is this problem with server side or with client side?Is this because I am not sending the data body using form??I know that 200 response mean that  connection is ok.But I just want to know why I dont get the JSON response like in a.

**volley**

Comment: Nope bro. I get the result for b. But why a is not displaying it.

Comment: Not sure if the problem is on client or server side. Can you try to make your request with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and see if there is a json body in the http response in the first case ? Sometimes, REST API only respond with 200 in the body when there is no data to return.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle already updated my question. Just test in postman but the result is display it like in b.

Comment: can you please update  your question with your code

Comment: @RohitSuthar already updated it with the code

Comment: instead of StringRequest  in volley make JsonObjectRequest

Answer (score 1):

That is because the method parseNetworkResponse.Disable this method.

```
                @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
```

surely you will get the json response after this.